# Использование NuGet зависимостей в SSDT проекте

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

При попытке вызвать `NuGet Package Manager` для `SSDT` проекта возникает ошибка, сообщающая о том, что поддержки для данного типа проекта нет.

---

Можно ли как-то обойти это ограничение c целью использования `NuGet` зависимостей в `SSDT` проекте?

---

Есть конечно вариант, создать обычный проект, но в таком случае будут отсутствовать многие удобные возможности, например развертывание сборки с последующим созданием оболочки в целевой БД.

Answer (score 1):

> `SSDT` проекты не поддерживаются - [Support for SQL Server Database Tools projects](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/545).

---

Для обхода данного ограничения был написан скрипт, который загружает `nuget.exe` и устанавливает, перечисленные в словаре зависимости, в заданный каталог:

```
$NugetUrl = 'https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe'

try {
    $NugetPath = (Get-Command -Name 'nuget.exe' -CommandType Application -ErrorAction Stop).Path
} catch  {
    $NugetPath = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'nuget.exe'
}

if (-not (Test-Path -Path $NugetPath -PathType Leaf)) {
    (New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($NugetUrl, $NugetPath)
}

$packages = @{

    'MongoDB.Driver'         = '2.5';
    'MongoDB.Driver.Core' = '2.5';
} 

foreach ($package in $packages.Keys) {
    & $NugetPath @(
        'install'
        $package
        '-Version'
        $packages.Item($package)
        '-ConfigFile'
        (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'Nuget.config')
        '-OutputDirectory'
        (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'packages')
    )
}
```

---

Вызов скрипта ощуствляется посредством `MSBuild` при сборке проекта:

```
<Target BeforeTargets="ResolveProjectReferences" Name="InstallPackage">
    <Exec Command="$(comspec) /k powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File .\install.ps1" WorkingDirectory="..\" />
</Target>
```

---

Однако, так как в используемом проекте зависимости статичны, то устанавливаются они вручную. В данном случае автоматизирована лишь загрузка библиотек с целью избежать создания побочных проектов и хранения бинарных файлов в репозитории.

---

`.sqlproj` это обычный `XML`. Для решения проблемы ручной установки зависимостей вы можете дописать соответствующий функционал, который добавлял бы `Reference` в проект на основе содержимого `$packages`:

```
<Reference Include="MongoDB.Driver">
    <HintPath>..\packages\MongoDB.Driver.2.5.0\lib\net45\MongoDB.Driver.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

---

- [How do I use Powershell to add/remove references to a csproj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963328/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-add-remove-references-to-a-csproj)
- [How to reference .NET assemblies using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079346/how-to-reference-net-assemblies-using-powershell)

---

[Project Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.buildengine.project?view=netframework-4.7.2) | [AddItemFast](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.additemfast?view=netframework-4.7.1#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_Project_AddItemFast_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Collections_Generic_KeyValuePair_System_String_System_String___)